# Mac app default working directory

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I've made many apps in Xcode before and always their default working directory was the one where the .app file is, so I've accessed the internal data like Whatever.app/Contents/Resources. I know it's probably not the right way, but it has always worked. Anyway, either from a recent Xcode update or for some other reason, their default working folder is now being set to "/". This only happens when I run the .app file from Finder. If I run it from within Xcode, the folder path is correct (I can set that path in the executable options, but it has no effect on what happens when you run the .app directly). Is this a setting somewhere or just the new standard?

Comment: This is not new - been like this in NeXT for 15+ years

Comment: **Never** make any assumptions about the initial working directory - your app will break in many different and interesting ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For resources, use this cool code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"awesomepic" ofType:@"png"];
```

You should never depend on PWD with Cocoa. Instead, use Cocoa API's whenever possible. BSD API's should only be used if Apple provided no other way.

---

## globheader.h

```
static char *appdir;
```

## appcontroller.m

```
#import "globheader.h"

@implementation AppController

- (void)method {
  appdir = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String];
}

@end
```

## cppcode.cpp

```
#include "globheader.h"

int main() {
  printf("%s", appdir);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the chunk of my code is in C++ and only uses Cocoa for windowing. Is there a handy Cocoa function to set the working path to the resource folder or something like that?

Comment: Change your file's extension from `.cpp` to `.mm`, import the Cocoa header and you can use Objective-C and C++ together.

Comment: Most of the code that loads files has to stay cross platform. I have OS-specific functions in the OS-wrappers, but a lot of the code uses the default working directory as a starting point. Is there a way to just set that from Cocoa? Or at least get the location of my .app file as a string?

Comment: You can create a global header file with a static variable and import it from your Objective-C, set it, and you can get it from C++. Note that you must use a C string literal and not an NSString. See -[NSString UTF8String]`.

Comment: You can set the working directory in Objective-C the same way as you would in C++ as long as you `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: I was looking for how to get the bundle path. I found it. [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] Thank you for your help!

Comment: @toastie, reload the page and I've inserted some sample code. :) HAVE FUN!

Comment: I just did: chdir([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String]);

Answer (score 2):

toastie, why use the application bundle to store data? don't change your .app.

Instread, use the application support folder. You can modify the bytes in that folder with no problems. Read the following post from Matt Gallagher,

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html

regards,